# Best practice for cross platform app animation (many & large)

Tags: html, flash, animation, cross-platform, coronasdk

What is the best practice for cross platform app's animation?
I have an app that has many animation, all of them in big resolutions and lots of frames.
I looked into most of the cross platform engines like Unity and Corona and non of them really suits my requirements - we're talking about 2D animation and when I tried using simply png frames and sprite sheets, the app's size went rediculesly huge.
I also tried exporting flash animations to html5 and although it worked very well (weighs almost nothing), it showed very poor performances.

EDIT to elaborate:

Video is of course an option, but I suppose there's a better solution, isn't there? Keep in mind that my animation has to happen on top of other things, like a background layer. Even if I did create a semi-transparent video, it would still be very not trivial to play it in an app without a platform-native player with controls etc.
It is kind of a 2d game. Let's say I have background image and I'm showing an animation clip on top of it whenever the user touches some button. Hoping to have a cross-platform app that supports multiple and high resolutions, sprite sheets might be huge.
Let's say I have an animation with half screen size and transparency, just this one sprite sheet can be huge in dimensions and weigh few MBs!

What do you say?

Comment: Depends. What kind of animation is it? If it’s a video (high resolution with lots of frames?), I’d recommend using a video.

Comment: What is the nature of the app? It seems to me that it's a 2d game. If it IS a 2d game, then I don't really see a problem with sprite sheets - I've yet to go wrong with them. A bit more elaboration would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's kind of rendered/recorded animation you should stick to video.
BUT If it's 2D object based animations, like I guess it is, you should go with vector animations and Corona is not the right choice.

You should try to move to Adobe AIR (3.5+) as it allows integration of your vector animations and your source files in a single package.

We had the exactly same issue (full screen animations on iPad and many of them, created by animation artists) and we switched from Corona to Adobe AIR because of the ridiculous app size when rendering those animations to PNGs.. Now we have multiple full screen animations for few seconds each weighing 300Kb!!